# SQL Select rows with duplicate data across multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql-server

If I have a table with first names, last names (which are composite unique) and takeaway choices, e.g.

```
+------+-------+---------+
|First | Last  | Food    |
+------+-------+---------+
|Bob   | Smith | Pizza   |
|Bob   | Smith | Chips   |
|Jim   | Smith | Pizza   |
|Lisa  | Jones | Pizza   |
|Lisa  | Jones | Chinese |
|Lisa  | James | Mexican |
|Eric  | White | Chinese |
|Eric  | White | Chips   |
+------+-------+---------+
```

I want all the rows corresponding to people who have at least two preferences for food, one of which is pizza. i.e. a result of

```
+------+-------+---------+
|First | Last  | Food    |
+------+-------+---------+
|Bob   | Smith | Pizza   |
|Bob   | Smith | Chips   |
|Lisa  | Jones | Pizza   |
|Lisa  | Jones | Chinese |
+------+-------+---------+
```

I've tried a join... group by ... having count(*) > 1 but it doesn't quite work how I want.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What you need is group by both first and last then having food count > 1

Comment: Notice you have two answers. Since you have tagged both sql-server and mysql the responses vary. You should tag the appropriate DBMS as those are not the same thing. Also, you really should look into normalization as what you posted is not normalized. And a unique constraint on first and last name combination is a poor design as it prevents two people with the same name.

Comment: Shouldn't 'Eric' be in your expected results too?

Comment: @McAdam331, I don't think OP would want Eric returned because Pizza is not one of the food preferences. I believe OP wants people with more than 1 food preference, where one of those preferences is pizza.

Comment: @ander2ed good catch. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way :P in SQL Server 2012+.

```
SELECT FIRST,LAST,FOOD FROM(
SELECT A.FIRST,A.LAST,B.FOOD,
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A.FIRST,A.LAST ORDER BY A.FIRST,A.LAST DESC) AS 'POS'
FROM TEST_FOOD A
INNER JOIN TEST_FOOD B
ON A.FIRST = B.FIRST
AND A.LAST = B.LAST
WHERE A.FOOD = 'PIZZA') TB WHERE POS = 2
```

And another more standard way in SQL Server 2005+, the first one is faster, but limited by MSSQL version.

```
SELECT C.FIRST,C.LAST,C.FOOD FROM 
(
SELECT A.FIRST,A.LAST FROM TEST_FOOD A
INNER JOIN TEST_FOOD B
ON A.FIRST = B.FIRST
AND A.LAST = B.LAST
WHERE B.FOOD = 'PIZZA'
GROUP BY A.FIRST,A.LAST
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) TB INNER JOIN 
TEST_FOOD C
ON TB.FIRST = C.FIRST
AND TB.LAST = C.LAST
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start by getting the list of first and last names that appear more than once:

```
SELECT first, last
FROM myTable
GROUP BY first, last
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Once you have that you can join it to your original table and make sure you're only selecting those names:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM myTable m
JOIN(
   SELECT first, last
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY first, last
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) tmp ON tmp.first = m.first AND tmp.last = m.last;
```

The problem with this query, though, is that it doesn't verify at least one of the person's preferred foods is pizza. To do that, we can just add an additional condition to our HAVING clause of the first subquery to check for one row of pizza. I did this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM myTable m
JOIN(
   SELECT first, last
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY first, last
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND SUM(food = 'Pizza') = 1) tmp ON tmp.first = m.first AND tmp.last = m.last;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cfadb/3) example.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT FIRST, LAST, MAX(FOOD) AS FOOD, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY FIRST, LAST
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2)
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE FIRST+LAST IN (SELECT FIRST+LAST FROM CTE)
```

There are many ways to do this. This is just one way.

Comment: OP also wanted to make sure one of the preferred foods was pizza, this query will pull anyone with at least two preferred foods, regardless of whether or not it includes pizza (sorry for copy paste comment @McAdam331)

Answer (score 0):

```
select first,last,GROUP_CONCAT(food separator ',') 
from people 
group by first,last 
having count(food) > 1 AND SUM(food = 'Pizza') = 1
```

Group concat will bring back the food in comma deliminated string.

```
+------+-------+---------------+
|First | Last  | Food          |
+------+-------+---------------+
|Bob   | Smith | Pizza,Chips   |
|Lisa  | Jones | Pizza,Chinese |
+------+-------+---------------+
```

Comment: OP also wanted to make sure one of the preferred foods was pizza, this query will pull anyone with at least two preferred foods, regardless of whether or not it includes pizza.

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this (using McAdam331's fiddle)...

```
 SELECT DISTINCT y.*
            FROM mytable x
            JOIN mytable y
              ON y.first = x.first
             AND y.last = x.last
            JOIN mytable z
              ON z.first = x.first
             AND z.last = x.last
             AND z.food <> y.food
           WHERE x.food = 'pizza';
```